# Node.js Forever List shows application is running when it is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have a simple queue display application in node.js.  It shows users in a queue on a display.  The application runs fine.  We have it running on many servers currently.  The problem is that, on a few servers, after a while (forever list shows one example as running for 15 days) it stops responding and netstat shows nothing listening on port 3000.

Code:

```
// Module dependindex.html
var express    = require('express'),
    mysql      = require('mys');

// Application initialization
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'mysql.host',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'pw',
      database : 'db',

    });
var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/components'));

// Page configuration (html pages are tempulates)
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// Application routes
// mysql calls/logic here
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var query = "SELECT aa.id, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, aa.gwf, ac.counter_stage, aa.queue_call_by_flag, ac.counter_name FROM `agent_counters` ac LEFT JOIN `applicants` aa ON aa.id = ac.next_applicant WHERE ac.call_next = 1 AND ac.next_applicant is not null";
  connection.query(query, req.body, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj = {};
    var prop = "";
    var gwf_name = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var current_stage = "";
      switch (rows[i].counter_stage) {
        case "documentation":
          current_stage = "Documentation";
          break;
        case "biometrics":
          current_stage = "Biometrics";
          break;
        case "interview":
          current_stage = "Interview";
          break;
      }
      prop = "gwf" + i;
      if (rows[i].queue_call_by_flag == 'gwf') {
        gwf_name = rows[i].gwf;
      } else {
        gwf_name = rows[i].first_name + ' ' + rows[i].last_name;
      }
      obj[prop] = gwf_name + '|' + rows[i].counter_name + '|' + current_stage + '|' + rows[i].id;
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
  });
});

// Begin listening
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", '3000', app.settings.env);
```

I have set the server to run with the Forever module Forever with the command:

```
Forever start app.js
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try running it with node at the first place? If the server throughs any error, forever may continue to restart it after your app crashes each time. Better run with command "node app.js" first to verify.

Comment: Do the logs say anything about mysql timing out?  That happened to us.

Comment: I've run it with node and node-dev.  The app works fine on most of the servers we are running it on.